# iptables:the meaning of default chain field

Tags: iptables, chain

for example,i have some chains like:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [368:102354]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [92952:20764374]
```

is there anyone who can explain what are the meanings of [368:102354]、[0:0] and [92952:20764374]?

Answer (score 0):

They are counters - numbers of packets and bytes which have been passed through chains.

Comment: you mean,they are always changing as more packets come through the iptables?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can zero byte counters with iptables -Z command.